# Apple LLVM 9.0 Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have recently updated my Xcode to version 9.0.1, but then my project cannot work properly in my iPhone, yet it can run correctly in the simulator. Here is the log infomation:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: aarch64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
/var/folders/45/mzdnwtsn6bx8wlzgl0svljdc0000gn/T/ExchangeHistoryController-141ae9.m
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/45/mzdnwtsn6bx8wlzgl0svljdc0000gn/T/ExchangeHistoryController-141ae9.cache
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/45/mzdnwtsn6bx8wlzgl0svljdc0000gn/T/ExchangeHistoryController-141ae9.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/45/mzdnwtsn6bx8wlzgl0svljdc0000gn/T/ExchangeHistoryController-141ae9.crash
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 

********************
```

I found online that some guys have met the same problem before and then turned off the bitcode in the Xcode build settings to fix this. I did the same thing , nothing worked for me. Does anybody have succeeded in fixing this? Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Xcode -> preference -> locations -> Derived Data

You should remove this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Xcode. Select Xcode -> Product -> Clean. Hope this may solve your issue. This worked for me.