# Unable to build xCode Project : Error Apple LLVM 9.0 Error Group

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I cant seem to build the react-native project. Tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841959/apple-llvm-9-0-error) however no progress. I am not using any pod files for this project, not sure whether that info is useful.

Below are my error messages :

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/......./node_modules/react-native/third-party/folly-2016.09.26.00/folly/StringBase.cpp'
>       clang: error: no input files

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project Drived Data:

```
Shift+Alt+Command+K
```